# TensorBoard refuses to open -- VersionConflict grpcio>=1.24.3

Tags: package-management, software-installation, python, pip, tensorflow

I have recently been having troubles with TensorBoard, as whenever I attempt to run the TensorBoard server, I get the error:

```
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (grpcio 1.21.1 (/home/me/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('grpcio>=1.24.3'))
```

I have attempted to run:

```
(sudo) pip3 install grpcio==1.24.3
```

However, running `pip3 list` reveals that grpcio is still version `1.21.1`

This leads me to believe that my installation of grpcio is not owned by pip and thus cannot be removed/upgraded by pip.  I then attempted to remove instances of grpcio in my `/usr/lib/python3.7` and `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages`, but pip is still reporting that grpcio is installed.

How do I resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since fixed the issue by changing my installed versions of TensorFlow

```
sudo pip3 install tensorflow==2.0.0 && sudo pip3 install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0 && sudo pip3 install tensorboard==2.0.0
```

Comment: What was your previously-installed version of tensorflow?